# Format date with Carbon and Laravel in one line

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

I retrieve this date format from my database: 2016-09-05T10:24:13Z

I need get this date and apply a diffForHumans() carbon method directly.

I have a ticket messages chats timeline:

```
@foreach($ticket->messages as $msg)
  <div class="chat-bubble>
    <div class="chat-msg">{{ $msg->message }}</div>
    <div class="chat-footer">{{ $msg->creation_date }}</div> //here needs carbon diff
  </div>
@endforeach
```

How can I use Carbon in my tickets.blade.php in one code line?

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach($ticket->messages as $msg)
  <div class="chat-bubble>
    <div class="chat-msg">{{ $msg->message }}</div>
    <div class="chat-footer">{{ $msg->creation_date->diffForHumans() }}</div> //here needs carbon diff
  </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: {!! \Carbon\Carbon::parse($msg->creation_date)->diffForHumans() !!}

Answer (score 0):

You should write this. Hopefully this will solve your problem

```
@foreach($ticket->messages as $msg)
  <div class="chat-bubble>
    <div class="chat-msg">{{ $msg->message }}</div>
    <div class="chat-footer">{{ $msg->creation_date->diffForHumans() }}</div> 
  </div>
@endforeach
```